# Active Directory Domain Services Installation Option Missing on Add Roles and Features Wizard

Tags: windows, active-directory, windows-server-2012, windows-server-2012-r2

I need to install Active Directory server on a Windows Server 2012 R2 Datacenter server. However, it seems that this option is missing on my system. As the Picture [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2CZf5.png) shows, I just have Active Directory Lightweight Directory Services and Active Directory Rights Management Services as enabled options to be installed. But they are not doable for what I need to do. Also, I have already installed SQL Server 2014.
How can I circunvent this issue?

Answer (score 3):

The feature is not available after SQL Server 2014 is installed.

> After SQL Server is installed on a computer, you cannot change the
>   computer from a domain member to a domain controller. You must
>   uninstall SQL Server before you change the host computer to a domain
>   controller.

Source: Michel Degremont | Premier Field Engineer – SQL Server Core Engineer | https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/mdegre/2011/06/25/can-i-install-sql-server-on-a-domain-controller/

Comment: Even though I reinstalled the OS and did not install SQL Server, I still does not have ADDS option enabled.

Comment: @user2294837 if iam not mistaken, Is it not 'Servicos Domino Active Directory' in your printscreen ?

Comment: you are precisely right! How can´t I see that?! I did not see that coming I read all of the others just to be sure that it was not written in Portuguese. Thanks a lot!

Comment: you are precisely right! How can´t I see that?! I did not see that coming I read all of the others just to be sure that it was not written in Portuguese. Thanks a lot!

Comment: @user2294837 my pleasure! dont forget to mark as answered if it answered you :)